# I want to use Window application in my ASP.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For this, I make windows application as a User Control from this Article..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14276/Using-Windows-Application-on-web

Now i am stuck at Step11.
Is that i have to add any dll or reg file in my web application??
or if not than what parameter i have to add in Object tag because i add whatever seen in this picture but when i see my design view it is showing that
"This control is not installed or count not be displayed"

Comment: Step 11, says add the dll - it doesnt mention reg files - so, did you do all the other steps are you sure you followed them? this was also written a while ago..  but I havent tried it to see what happens.. but it sounds like maybe you missed step 10, or havent done 11 quite right

Comment: Not all articles on CodeProject are good. This is a clear example of a bad article, its rating should be a warning as well. (15 people rated it as 1.)

Comment: @BugFinder 
I did step 10 and its done successfully. i also add dll but its not working.

Comment: @ShadowWizard
This article is fully copied from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-a-windows-application-on-the-web/

Comment: @ShadowWizard- Is there any article where i can find, to make window application as user control and use it into my web application??

Comment: So? It's the same person. It's still bad, because it's something he did for himself then just shared as-is without clear explanations how to achieve each step

Comment: I can't find a reason why not create an .ascx User Control.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no magic trick for this. Either ultra-complicated (and usually non-working) way like what you found, or just re-write it from scratch, copying relevant parts where you can

Comment: The article is from 2006, is based on .Net 1.1, and uses ActiveX. Hardly future-proof